# Use continuity to show that a function is continuous on an interval

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Use the definition of continuity and the properties of limits to show that the function $g(x)= 2\sqrt{3-x}$ is continuous on the interval $(-\infty,3]$.

I know that for a function to be continuous, the limit of the function as $x$ approaches $a$ should be equal to $f(a)$.

So for the function $g(x)$ above to be continuous, the function should be continuous on the left of $3$ and at $3$.

But my problem is I don't know how to clearly present/write my answer.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Which definition of "limit of a function" are you working with?

Comment: @DanielFischer The limit of f(x), as x approaches a, equals L, if we can make the values of f(x) arbitrarily close to L by taking x to be sufficiently close to a but not equal to a

Answer (score 1):

The function is only left continous .

You cannot apply the right hand limit as your domain doesnt allow you to take values greater then 3 .

Comment: The function is continuous. There are some stupid definitions of the limit of a function that confuse people, but for continuity, only points in the domain of the function can matter at all.

Comment: You are right @DanielFischer . Strictly speaking the function is discontinous at 3 .

Comment: No, the function is continuous at $3$. For all $x$ in the domain with $\lvert x-3\rvert < \frac{\varepsilon^2}{4}$, we have $\lvert f(x) - f(3)\rvert < \varepsilon$.

Comment: @DanielFischer But how to I write my solution? I'm not sure how to answer the question. Can you please give a detailed answer? I would really appreciate it.
Thanks